# How can i reset list viewModel

Tags: jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a list of model same as Knockoutjs live example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7RDc3/

Main:

```
var viewModel = new GiftModel([
{ name: "Tall Hat", price: "39.95"},
{ name: "Long Cloak", price: "120.00"}
]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

How can i reset object viewModel  to null or `new GiftModel([])` by button click event `(not use knock out event)`, i want whenever click button, Grid will empty Gift.
Example :

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
clearKnockOutViewModel();
});
```

---> viewModel will empty and html will clear.

Comment: You can't (easily) create a new viewmodel and bind it, and you probably don't want to. You want to reset the data in your current viewmodel. This can be done by setting all the observables back to their initial state. If you show the code for your GiftModel constructor, we can suggest how you would achieve this.

Comment: You want to clean node? Or just clear the viewmodel and reapply bindings?

Comment: i just want clear the viewmodel and reapply bindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the right way.

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
clearKnockOutViewModel();
});

function clearKnockOutViewModel(){
  var element = $('#elementId')[0]; 
  ko.cleanNode(element);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel, element);
}
```

You will loose the viewModel logic if you empty it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` to pop each item.

```
<button data-bind='click: clearGifts'>Clear Gifts</button>

self.clearGifts = function() {
    var length = self.gifts().length;
    for (var i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
       self.gifts.pop();
    }
};
```

Edit: If gifts is an observableArray you can use removeAll.

```
self.clearGifts = function() {
    self.gifts.removeAll();
};
```

Comment: (not use knock out event),$( "#event" ).click(function() {
clearKnockOutViewModel();
});

Comment: If gifts is an observableArray you can also call "gifts.removeAll()"

Comment: @BenjaminPaul, feel free to edit, but the OP wants to use jquery anyway

Comment: Edited for completeness!